# Is CoreML local to the device (iOS)?

Tags: ios, coreml

I want to leverage AI and Machine learning and develop a mobile app in iOS. I plan to start with clothes but branch into other verticals as well (tools, appliances, etc.). The goal is to blend the in-store experience with mobile commerce, on a personal level (e.g. integrated retail). The app will come prepared with recommendations from the start, but should also continue to learn based on customer preferences as they shop with the app. I need to figure out how to tie this in with Major retailer's APIs as well.

Is something like this possible using CoreML? Or is CoreML something that is local to the device and I would need something that is cloud based so I can tie in with Major retailer APIs?

Comment: When you use CoreML your model and it's logic will only limited to iOS. If you're planning for expansion and developing an Android app as well, then you will need to write and need to use some other technique to do the same thing in that new app. Moreover, keeping model within app will increase the size of the app if you really wanna make an app it's better to write all this ML logic on your server and create APIs which will work for multiple platforms. Since few days I am thinking to do something like that and I end up having this flow if I will start building that idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe IBM Watson can address your problem the best. It allows to establish a pipeline where device will upload new data to the cloud and updated models will be pushed back to the device. See https://developer.apple.com/ibm/

I tried their SDK, it works pretty straightforward. I had a problem using UK node of Watson, so I had to switch to US node - and it worked perfectly.